# Use Creation Policy in CloudFormation for EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have a CloudFormation template where I install logstash on an EC2 instance.

By default, the user data scripts are executed one time when you launch the instance. So I configured `cfn-hup` to execute a certain configSet for when a config file or something is updated in the CloudFormation template. It seems to work okay.

This is the important snippet of my template.

```
  LogstashInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ...
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash
          /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackId} --resource LogstashInstance --region ${AWS::Region} --configsets default
          /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack ${AWS::StackId} --resource LogstashInstance --region ${AWS::Region}
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
        configSets:
          # These scripts will run during the instance launch triggered by the userData
          default:
            - 01_xx
            - 02_xx
            - 03_xx
            - 04_xx
          # These scripts will run during an update of the instance metadata = stack update.
          UpdateEnvironment:
            - 03_xx
            - 04_xx
        01_setup_cfn_hup:
          files:
            '/etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf':
              content: !Sub |
                [main]
                stack=${AWS::StackId}
                region=${AWS::Region}
                interval=1
              mode: '000400'
              owner: root
              group: root
            '/etc/cfn/hooks.d/logastash-auto-reloader.conf':
              content: !Sub |
                [cfn-auto-reloader-hook]
                triggers=post.update
                path=Resources.LogstashInstance.Metadata.AWS::CloudFormation::Init
                action=/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackId} --resource LogstashInstance --region ${AWS::Region} --configsets UpdateEnvironment
                runas=root
              mode: '000400'
              owner: root
              group: root
            '/lib/systemd/system/cfn-hup.service':
              content: |
                [Unit]
                Description=cfn-hup daemon
                [Service]
                Type=simple
                ExecStart=/opt/aws/bin/cfn-hup
                Restart=always
                [Install]
                WantedBy=multi-user.target
          commands:
            01_enable_cfn_hup:
              command: systemctl enable cfn-hup.service
            02_start_cfn_hup:
              command: systemctl start cfn-hup.service
```

Now my problem is that it can take a while before all configsets are executed, but in the CloudFormation console the stack update is completed before even knowing if the update went well.

I want to use a `creationPolicy` so my stack update in cloudformation will only be successful when everything is finished (so all commands and file updates triggered by `cfn-hup`).

I added a creationpolicy:

```
CreationPolicy:
  ResourceSignal:
    Count: 1
    Timeout: PT15M
```

I've added a `cfn-signal` in my userdata:

```
/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack ${AWS::StackId} --resource LogstashInstance --region ${AWS::Region}
```

But this will only be executed during instance launch. How can I implement the `cfn-signal` in my `cfn-hup` configuration so that it signals back when an update took place without a new instance launch.